# switch case of greater than or less than variable

Tags: javascript

I use this code to enter a number and compare it using less and greater than within switch case how should I do to get the correct result, only default can works

```
var sum=prompt("enter sum:");

// sum=50;
switch(sum)
{
case sum=0:
  alert("sucess");
  break;
case sum>50:
  alert("also sucess");
  break;
case sum<50:
  alert("failed");
default:
 alert("there is errorrrr");

}
```

Comment: first case should be `case sum == 0:` And 50 goes to default since none of conditions not met

Comment: @Progressive Actually it's [generally considered better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) if it's `case sum === 0:`

Comment: @NikKyriakides you are absolutely right. Old habits (c# guy here) die hard =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `switch (true)`:

```
switch (true) {
  case sum === 0:
    alert('success');
    break;
  case sum < 50:
    alert('also success');
    break;
  case sum > 50:
    alert('failed');
    break;
  default:
    alert('there is an error.')
    break;
}
```

Note that in your code, the first case is actually an assignment and modify `sum` to set it to 0.

Comment: also worth noting that the return value of a `prompt` is a string. conversion will have to happen for the comparisons to have meaningful results.

Answer (score -1):

It actually doesn't work, as you expect, the switch statement is compared against all cases, such as :

```
switch (something)
{
    case 1: // something == 1 ?
    // ....
}
```

Actually, what you have write was interpreted such as

```
var sum = 42;
switch(sum)
{
    case sum < 50: // sum == sum < 50 ? -> 42 == 42 < 50 ? -> 42 == true ? false !
    // ...
```

Instead, you can use a switch true statement.

```js
//        v-------     convert the prompt to a numeric value
let sum = + prompt("enter sum:");

switch(true)
{
//         VV----- notice the double equal
  case sum == 0:       // true == sum == 0 ? 
    alert("sucess");
    break;
  case sum > 50:
    alert("also sucess");
    break;
  case sum < 50:
    alert("failed");
    break;     //  <---- You forgot a break; there
  default:
    alert("there is errorrrr");
    break;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why I've been downvoted

Answer (score -1):

ur idea works fine

```js
sum=20;
switch(true)
{
case 50:
  alert("sucess");
  break;
case (sum>50):
  alert("also sucess");
  break;
case sum<50:
  alert("failed");
 break;        
default:
 alert("there is errorrrr");

}
```

Comment: Won't work if sum is different than 50.

Comment: if forgot to change variable to `true` add `break;` in 3rd case